# Error while re indexing product flat data

Tags: magento-1.9

exception 'PDOException' with message

```
'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'magento.#sql-16f6_225' (errno: 121)' in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(423): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#7 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2833): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(815): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->addForeignKey('FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT...', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE')
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1389): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(2)
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(350): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#13 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/html/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /var/www/html/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty this is caused by the fact that the MySQL user assigned to Magento (see in `app/etc/local.xml`) does not have the privilege to create tables.

You can find that by running the following in MySQL:

```
GRANT CREATE ON database TO 'user'@'host';
```

Where you have to replace:

- database: the name of your Magento database
- user: the name of the MySQL user assigned to Magento
- host: your host

Answer (score 0):

Mysql can't create table errno 121

You will get this message if you are trying to add a constraint with a name that is already used somewhere else.

To check constraints, use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    constraint_name,
    table_name
FROM
    information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE
    constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
AND table_schema = DATABASE()
ORDER BY
    constraint_name;
```

Reference: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/425/error-creating-foreign-key-from-mysql-workbench